# openssl pkcs12 command programmatically Objective-C / C

Tags: c, openssl, key, extract, private

I am trying to get the private key from a p12 file in C.
In console I can just type

openssl pkcs12 -in some.p12 -out kestore.pem -nodes

and in the pem I have the private key.

I managed to load the p12 file like this

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] pathForResource:@"some" ofType:@"p12"];
    const char *pathCString = [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    FILE *p12File = fopen(pathCString, "rb");
    if (p12File == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    PKCS12 *p12 = NULL;
    p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(p12File, NULL);

    if (p12 != NULL) {
        const char *pw = "supersecretpass";
        //int PKCS12_parse(PKCS12 * p12, const char *pass, EVP_PKEY **pkey, X509 **cert, STACK_OF(X509) * *ca);
        EVP_PKEY *pkey;
        X509 *cert;
        STACK_OF(X509) * ca;
        int result = PKCS12_parse(p12, pw, &pkey, &cert, &ca);
        NSLog(@"result %d", result);
        PKCS12_free(p12);
    }

    fclose(p12File);
    return nil;
```

How do I get the private key now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is in your `EVP_PKEY *pkey` object. This object is an abstract key (EVP = envelop) but you can extract the real key from depending of what kind of key do you have :

```
 RSA *EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(EVP_PKEY *pkey);
 DSA *EVP_PKEY_get1_DSA(EVP_PKEY *pkey);
 DH *EVP_PKEY_get1_DH(EVP_PKEY *pkey);
 EC_KEY *EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY(EVP_PKEY *pkey);
```

Here the documentation about it : https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA.html

For example, if you have a RSA key, you have all the components of a private/public key pair  which are really big numbers store in `BIGNUM` objects :

```
 const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_n(const RSA *d);
 const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_e(const RSA *d);
 const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_d(const RSA *d);
 const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_p(const RSA *d);
 const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_q(const RSA *d);
 const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_dmp1(const RSA *r);
 const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_dmq1(const RSA *r);
 const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_iqmp(const RSA *r);
 void RSA_get0_key(const RSA *r, const BIGNUM **n, const BIGNUM **e, const BIGNUM **d);
 void RSA_get0_factors(const RSA *r, const BIGNUM **p, const BIGNUM **q);
```

Here the documentation about it :

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/RSA_get0_e.html

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/RSA_get0_key.html